# Play Framework: how to auto-login with Secure module upon user registration?

Tags: authentication, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am using Play Framework 1.2.4

My main controller is protected with the "secure" module.

Now, I need to add a process to register a new user for the system. I implement it in another controller. Assuming the registration process is successful, I would like to display the "home page" for the newly created user, without asking to type username / password again.

How to achieve that?

A bit of "simplified" code:

In the Registration controller:

```
public static void newUser(String username, String password, String fullname)
{
   User user = new User(username, password, fullname);
   user.save();
   // What is the trick to avoid login being displayed???
   MainController.index();
 }
```

MainController is using the "secure" module.

Thanks for any hint,

Max

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like the answer is here:
[How to use play frameworks Secure module to login a user after that user has been created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103544/how-to-use-play-frameworks-secure-module-to-login-a-user-after-that-user-has-bee?rq=1)

I found it after I posted.

Max